# Issues with Angular bundle size decreasing

Tags: angular, npm, optimization, bundle, production

I'm asking for some help to reduce our project bundle size
I tried to apply a lot of techniques
First I removed unused third libraries;

```
"lodash": "^4.17.19",
"luxon": "^1.27.0",
"minimatch": "~3.0.4",
"moment": "^2.27.0",
"moment-timezone": "^0.5.31",
```

Optimize imports from libraries:

```
import * as yaml from 'js-yaml';
import { yaml } from 'js-yaml';

import * as uuid from 'uuid';
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';
```

But no impact in the bundle size .. always the same
I tried to run `source-map-explorer` and `webpack-bundle-analyzer` but always no changes ..
So asking if there is a cache used ?

Answer (score 1):

You should inspect your bundle.

Install webpack-bundle-analyzer.

```
npm install --save-dev webpack-bundle-analyzer@4.4.2
```

Add this to your package.json > scripts.

```
 "build:stats": "ng build --stats-json",
 "analyze": "webpack-bundle-analyzer dist/<project>/stats.json"
```

When running `analyze` you´ll get a nice GUI of whats taking up bundle size.

In my case it was extensive usage of wrong @import(s) in scss files, which greatly increases your bundle size.

Analyze: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/angular-angular-webpack-bundle-analyzer

Scss imports. https://blog.profanis.me/blog/mind-your-imports-and-save-the-bundle-size

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to cut the bundle size you can try to look in the packages code and take Only the parts you need.

For example in `lodash` there are many useful function but I can assume you are only use some of them, so you can edit the third party packages and recreate them on your personal repository.

Useful link: https://teambrookvale.com.au/articles/modifying-npm-packages-the-right-way

not the best thing to do but works.

Also, to reduce application loading time you can implement Angulars `Lazy-loading feature`. docs: https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules

Hope it helped, happy coding :)

Comment: Well I removed loadash completely but the bundle size still the same